# Calling an API endpoint from within another route in Node / Express

Tags: node.js, express

I have myRoute.js with a route (GET) defined and I want to call an api endpoint from another route (api.js), and I'm not sure what the right way to do this is. The api.js route is working properly (image and code below).

### **api.js**

```
router.get('/getGroups/:uid', function(req, res, next) {    
  let uid = req.params.uid;
  db.getAllGroups(uid).then((data) => {
    let response =[];
    for (i in data) {
      response.push(data[i].groupname);
    }
    res.status(200).send(response);
   })
   .catch(function (err) {
     return err;  
   });  
});
```

works as expected:

[image]

**myRoute.js**

I would like when a user goes to localhost:3000/USER_ID that the route definition gets information from the api. Psuedo code below (someFunction).

```
router.get('/:uid', function(req, res, next) {
  let uid = req.params.uid;
  let fromApi = someFunction(`localhost:3000/getAllGroups/${uid}`); // <--!!!
  console.log(fromApi) ;  //expecting array
  res.render('./personal/index.jade', {fromApi JSON stringified});
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use fetch for this. You can replace `someFunction` with `fetch`, and then put the `res.render` code in a `.then()`. So, you would get this:

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

router.get('/:uid', function(req, res, next) {
  let uid = req.params.uid;
  fetch('localhost:3000/getAllGroups/${uid}').then(res => res.json()).then(function(data) {
    returned = data.json();
    console.log(returned);  //expecting array
    res.render('./personal/index.jade', {JSON.stringify(returned)});
  });
});
```

A more robust way with error handling would be to write something like this:

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

function handleErrors(response) {
  if(!response.ok) {
    throw new Error("Request failed " + response.statusText);
  }
  return response;
}

router.get('/:uid', function(req, res, next) {
  let uid = req.params.uid;
  fetch('localhost:3000/getAllGroups/${uid}')
  .then(handleErrors)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log(data) ;  //expecting array
    res.render('./personal/index.jade', {JSON.stringify(data)});
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    // handle the error here
  })
});
```

The ideal way would be to abstract your code into a method so you aren't calling yourself, as The Reason said. However, if you really want to call yourself, this will work.

Comment: Thanks. I get the following result as a console output: Response { size: 0, timeout: 0 }, however, if I try the url in the browser it works as expected. fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/getGroups/${uid}`)
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log('result:', data) ;
    res.render('./personal/index.jade', {leftNav: JSON.stringify(data)});
  })
  .catch(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  });

Comment: hmm.. now I get the following error: result: Promise { <pending> }
GET /personal/1 200 109.871 ms - 9901
(node:21270) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 4): TypeError: body used already for: http://localhost:3000/api/getGroups/1

Comment: Ok - error message is gone (progress woot!), however, now I get: result: Promise { <pending> }

Comment: if you add this to your answer I will mark it as accepted: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch and then using their example:
fetch('https://api.github.com/users/github')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json));

Comment: If these API's live on the same host, you're hurting yourself with performance by creating an HTTP network connection. If the data lives in a database on the same host, you're doing multiple network requests on a single API call. Best thing to do would be us a proxy or extract your API function outside of the route so it can be used directly in multiple routes.

Comment: Agreed - that's what I would do. However, I figured I ought to at least show how to call an API, since that's what OP asked for.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if i understand you correct but anyway i will try to help. So you have an api like

```
router.get('/getGroups/:uid', function(req, res, next) {    
  let uid = req.params.uid;
  db.getAllGroups(uid).then((data) => {
    let response =[];
    for (i in data) {
      response.push(data[i].groupname);
    }
    res.status(200).send(response);
   })
   .catch(function (err) {
     return err;  
   });  
});
```

If you would like to reuse it you can extract a function from the code above like so:

```
async function getAllGroupsByUserId(uid){
  const result = [];
  try{
    const data = await db.getAllGroups(uid);
    for (i in data) {
      result.push(data[i].groupname);
    };
    return result;
  }
  catch(e) {
    return e;
  }
}
```

And then reuse it in your api & anywhere you want:

```
router.get('/getGroups/:uid', async function(req, res, next) {    
  const uid = req.params.uid;
  const groups = await getAllGroupsByUserId(uid);
  res.status(200).send(groups);
})
```

Same you can do in your another route:

```
router.get('/:uid', async function(req, res, next) {
  const uid = req.params.uid;
  const fromApi = await getAllGroupsByUserId(uid); // <--!!!
  console.log(fromApi) ;  //expecting array
  res.render('./personal/index.jade', {fromApi JSON stringified});
});
```

Seems like pretty clear :)

Comment: I think keeping your code DRY and not calling yourself through fetch is the way to go.  If you decide to go this route Ron, you'll want to handle the error care in the `/getGroups/:uid` route.  With the current implementation it will return a 200 with the error as the body.

Comment: @DanielMoses He can always wrap an async function in a `try\catch` :)