# Call Express router manually

Tags: node.js, performance, express

Нello! I am looking to call a function which has been passed to an `expressRouter.post(...)` call.

This `expressRouter.post(...)` call is occurring in a file which I **am unable to modify**. The code has already been distributed to many clients and there is no procedure for me to modify their versions of the file. While *I* have no ability to update this file for remote clients, *other developers are able to*. I therefore face the issue of this POST endpoint's behaviour changing in the future.

I am also dealing with performance concerns. This POST endpoint expects `req.body` to be a parsed JSON object, and that JSON object can be excessively large.

My goal is to write a GET endpoint which internally activates this POST endpoint. The GET endpoint will need to call the POST endpoint with a very large JSON value, which has had URL query params inserted into it. The GET's functionality should always mirror the POST's functionality, including if the POST's functionality is updated in the future. For this reason I cannot copy/paste the POST's logic. Note also that the JSON format will never change.

I understand that the issue of calling an expressjs endpoint internally has conventionally been solved by either 1) [extracting the router function into an accessible scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51570745/how-to-run-endpoint-on-express-start), or 2) [generating an HTTP request to localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51369866/calling-an-api-endpoint-from-within-another-route-in-node-express).

Unfortunately in my case neither of these options are viable:

1. I can't move the function into an accessible scope as I can't modify the source, nor can I copy-paste the function as the original version may change
2. Avoiding the HTTP request is a high priority due to performance considerations. The HTTP request will require serializing+deserializing an excessively large JSON body, re-visiting a number of authentication middlewares (which require waiting for further HTTP requests + database queries to complete), etc

Here is my (contrived) POST endpoint:

```
expressRouter.post('/my/post/endpoint', (req, res) => {

  if (!req.body.hasOwnProperty('val'))
    return res.status(400).send('Missing "val"');

  return res.status(200).send(`Your val: ${req.body.val}`);

});
```

If I make a POST request to `localhost:<port>/my/post/endpoint` I get the expected error or response based on whether I included "val" in the JSON body.

Now, I want to have exactly the same functionality available, but via GET, and with "val" supplied in the URL instead of in any JSON body. I have attempted the following:

```
expressRouter.get('/my/get/endpoint/:val', (req, res) => {

  // Make it seem as if "val" occurred inside the JSON body
  let fakeReq = {
    body: {
      val: req.params.val
    }
  };

  // Now call the POST endpoint
  // Pass the fake request, and the real response
  // This should enable the POST endpoint to write data to the
  // response, and it will seem like THIS endpoint wrote to the
  // response.
  manuallyCallExpressEndpoint(expressRouter, 'POST', '/my/post/endpoint', fakeReq, res);

});
```

Unfortunately I don't know how to implement `manuallyCallExpressEndpoint`.

Is there a solution to this problem which excludes both extracting the function into an accessible scope, and generating an HTTP request?

Comment: Have you consider this: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_url_options_callback ?

Comment: *"Pretend I don't have access to the file where it's defined"* - why? If it's part of the same application, extracting the relevant business-layer method and invoking it directly is by far the simplest and most performant way to achieve this.

Comment: Yes - `require('http').get` will generate an HTTP request, which I'd like to avoid. There are several reasons why; for one it would require me to serialize/deserialize my JSON body which shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: I'm not sure yet what's the goal of your approach...

Comment: @jonrsharpe - For two reasons! Firstly, I'd like to understand expressjs better. And second, sometimes code maintainers will be reluctant to let people modify their code. They may have any number of reasons for rejecting changes.

Comment: How do you think making a request from within the application help you understand Express any better than making a request from outside? And *are* those code maintainers reluctant? If so, why not ask *them* to expose the functionality you need?

Comment: @MarceloFilho A function exists, passed to `app.post('my/post/endpoint'...)`. This function is held in memory by expressjs. This function accomplishes exactly what I need, if I pass it my own `req` and `res` params. That's why I'd like to be able to call this function as directly as possible.

Comment: This might help you: https://scotch.io/tutorials/test-a-node-restful-api-with-mocha-and-chai

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'll understand expressjs better if I understand where in memory it's holding the function I passed to `app.post(...)`. I could ask code maintainers to make changes; of course they either may or may not.

Comment: I'm sorry, reading your answers I'm getting more confuse what do you really want to. If want to understand the Express behavior I would suggest you debug or inject a few console outputs in the Express code. Or if you want to perform tests I would suggest you go for https://scotch.io/tutorials/test-a-node-restful-api-with-mocha-and-chai, or you can just export your GET callback in a method and call it faking the data...

Comment: What do you mean *"where in memory"*? It's unclear what options you think you have, but it's either: 1. make a new HTTP request from the app to itself; or 2. extract a function and just call it. It should be clear which is likely to make sense,

Comment: The 2nd option is exactly what I'm interested in accomplishing! Generating a new HTTP request has a whole bunch of overhead. Imagine if the JSON body were 50mb large; it would require serialization + deserialization, which seems an unacceptable amount of overhead.

Comment: You usually DON'T want to call endpoints directly from within your server.  It's just darn inefficient.  Instead, you take the code for the endpoint you want to call, put the appropriate part it in a shared function and then you can call it from multiple places.  It's just code sharing like you would do anywhere else in your Javascript.  Just because it's a route doesn't make it anything special.  People tend to forget all the normal coding practices just because they are routes (for some unknown reason).

Comment: Of course the ideal solution is to move all shared functionality between the GET/POST endpoints into a common function - but that's outside of what I'm looking for with this specific question.

Comment: Well, STOP pursuing the wrong option.  You shouldn't be avoiding the correct way of coding just because of some obstinate maintainer of a section of code.  You should very well be able to show that your modification does not change the results of the previous route in any way, while allowing you to efficient reuse some of their code for other useful purposes.

Comment: If you just want the inefficient way of calling an existing route in your own server, just go get the `request()` module and call your own server.  Express does not have any unique support for it because it's generally not considered a desirable thing to do.

Comment: I agree that it's frustraing to code less correctly because of obstinate maintainers! I've already mentioned why I'd like to avoid an HTTP request.

Comment: @GershomMaes why you dont get the downvotes? Did you read the comments above? As long as you dont give us a clear scenario where you must do this way we cant agree upon you go for this approach, it just doesnt make sense at all! Why would you call the framework code to process the fake POST call when you can just call the extract method? If you dont have an answer for that is clear that you want to do this weird way just because you want to not you need to...

Comment: This question is specifically asking about how to accomplish this without affecting the code in `app.post(...)`. That's the question. You don't have to answer it if you don't know how to do it, but it is a *constraint of the question*, the same way that many other great questions on this site have constraints. It doesn't deserve to be downvoted imo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems possible, but it may make more sense to modify `req` and pass it, rather than create a whole new `fakeReq` object. The thing which enables this looks to be the `router.handle(req, res, next)` function. I'm not sure this is the smartest way to go about this, but it will certainly avoid the large overhead of a separate http request!

```
app.get('/my/get/endpoint/:val', (req, res) => {

  // Modify `req`, don't create a whole new `fakeReq`
  req.body = {
    val: req.params.val
  };

  manuallyCallExpressEndpoint(app, 'POST', '/my/post/endpoint', req, res);

});

let manuallyCallExpressEndpoint = (router, method, url, req, res) => {
  req.method = method;
  req.url = url;
  router.handle(req, res, () => {});
};
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a simple middleware?

```
function checkVal(req, res, next) {
  const val = req.params.val || req.body.val

  if (!val) {
    return res.status(400).send('Missing "val"'); 
  }

  return res.status(200).send(`Your val: ${val}`);
}

app.get('/my/get/endpoint/:val', checkVal)
app.post('/my/post/endpoint', checkVal)
```

This code isn't tested but gives you rough idea on how you can have the same code run in both places.

The checkVal function serves as a Express handler, with request, response and next. It checks for params first then the body.

Comment: Unfortunately this requires me to change the function passed to `app.post(...)` which I'd prefer to avoid.

Comment: I understand, I am not sure you can achieve what you want. You want to execute the same piece of code in two different locations, without wrapping it in a function or making a http call. Is that correct?

Comment: @GershomMaes you will have to change the code anyway!

Comment: @Bergur yes that's right! The function must be somewhere in memory. I don't want to copy/paste it for maintainability reasons, and due to the constraints of the question I don't want to modify the `app.post(...)` code.

Comment: @MarceloFilho If you look to my answer it looks like a solution was possible, without needing to change the code!

Comment: @GershomMaes ok im done trying to understand your goal... if you have to implement the `manuallyCallExpressEndpoint ` you have to change the code anyway... good luck!